# IBMQFactory object has not attribute backends

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I try to run simple circuit measurement program using Qiskit in Visual Code.  I received this error:

`AttributeError: 'IBMQFactory' object has no attribute 'backend'`

from the line of code  `print(IBMQ.backends())`

**Does anyone know what this mean and how to solve it?**

Answer (score 2):

With the help of documentation from this URL https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider, I realized that I need to run `load_account()` of my `APIToken` and store the provider object as shown below

```
my_provider = IBMQ.load_account()
print(my_provider.backends())
backend = my_provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
```